# Python3: Unable to split word from parsed data

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, mapreduce

I am creating a MapReduce job to find 'ArticleTitle' from an XML file. I am working on mapper.py to identify the tags and split it based on the letters.
Following is the script:

```
tree = ET.parse('File location')
doc = tree.getroot()
for ArticleTitle in doc.iter('ArticleTitle'):
    file1 = (ET.tostring(ArticleTitle, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))
    filename = file1[52:(len(file1))]
    Article_Title= filename.split("<")[0]
    # print(Article_Title)
    for line in Article_Title:
        line_1= re.findall(r"\w+|[^\w\s]", line, re.UNICODE)
        print(line_1)
```

The output I am getting is:

```
['T']['h']['e'][]['e']['f']['f']['e']['c']['t'][]['o']['f']
```

However, I want the output to be:

```
['The', 'effect', 'of', 'Hene', 'laser']
```

Comment: Why are you using regex instead of the xml parser?

Comment: Article Title is a string. If you loop through a string, you get back individual characters. If you want the whole words you don't need the loop - just do `Article_Title.split()`.

Comment: @KuboMD Make it an answer.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I have used ElementTree to parse the data, it's just that I need to map the words from the parsed data that I am finding an issue with

Comment: @KuboMD thanks for the reply! This worked. If you could comment as an answer I could upvote

Comment: Sure, thanks for the offer :)

Comment: @RRg Make sure you accept the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Article Title` is a string. See:

```
Article_Title= filename.split("<")[0]
```

If you loop through a string, you get back individual characters.

```
for i in "hello!":
    print(i)

>>>>h
>>>>e
>>>>l
>>>>l
>>>>o
>>>>!
```

If you want the whole words you don't need the loop - just do `Article_Title.split()`

```
"The effect of Hene laser" --> ['The', 'effect', 'of', 'Hene', 'laser']
```